# save client html changes

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a div element that contains a ul element that starts off empty when the page is first loaded.  The user can then drag li elements into this div box which will populate the ul element.  I need to be able to retain the li elements that have been added to the ul container so that I can show the li elements after a post back.  How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="sidebar-drop-box">              
                 <p class="dropTitle"><strong>Drop Box</strong><br />  
                     Drag and drop tracks here temporarily if you’re working with a long playlist.</p>  
                 <ul class="admin-song-list"></ul>  
         </div>
```

the drag and drop is done with javascript and jquery.  All of this sits on a asp.net page.  when the drag is completed this is code that is executed

```
function AddToDropBox(obj) {
    $(obj).children(".handle").animate({ width: "20px" }).children("strong").fadeOut();
    $(obj).children("span:not(.track,.play,.handle,:has(.btn-edit))").fadeOut('fast');
    $(obj).children(".play").css("margin-right", "8px");
    $(obj).css({ "opacity": "0.0", "width": "284px" }).animate({ opacity: "1.0" });
    if ($(".sidebar-drop-box ul").children(".admin-song").length > 0) {
        $(".dropTitle").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".sidebar-drop-box ul.admin-song-list").css("min-height", "0");
    }
    if (typeof SetLinks == 'function') {
        SetLinks();
    }
```

So i tried this code below to go through and get all the elements that are suppose to be in the drop down box and put them back.  but it didnt add them to the drop box it made the changes to the master list

```
//repopulate drop box
    if(document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value!="")
        {
            var localRemoveMedias=document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value.split(",");
            $(".admin-left li.admin-song").each(function(){
//                alert("inEach");//WORKS
                for(x in localRemoveMedias)
                {
                    if($(this).attr("mediaid")==localRemoveMedias[x])
                    {
                        AddToDropBox($(this));
                    }
                }//end for
            });//function(){
        }
```

Comment: You might want to provide some more info like the framework in particular you are using to perform the drag/drop operation.  Every one of those tools have different ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Wouldn't making an AJAX request to the server when the drop is done on the client side to store away the state give you the ability to do what you want? I might be confused. I am not sure where the postback is making the update to the server ...

Comment: Did you tried to send your control's `.innerHtml` property as string to the server? Maybe also that setting `runat=server` in your control, you can automatically get the updated content when submitting the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

To retain your dragged elements across postback I suggest you to store your elements IDs in an asp:hiddenfield as your user do his drag/drop operations.

When postback will occur your IDs will be persisted and you will be able to recreate your page state as it was before postback.

Answer (score 0):

For Drag and Drop operations, generally the post back is not required. You can do your server side updates using Ajax which will eliminate the creation of Page state altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Apples and Oranges.  Why are you posting back?  I was doing the same thing when I started to use Ajax. I had a litle bit of nice Ajax functionality and whole lot of old school state driven viewstateenabled="true" good old .Net in one page.  Is what we are being fed for the last 10 yrs.  I was saving the state of the changes as I made them on the client and then I was manuvering on the server to maintain the changes between postbacks.  I found that the less I used postbacks and the more I developed in a stateless state of mind.  If you can avoid the post back make an Ajax call to the server and do what you have to do, return the results and redraw accordingly.